# Installing MySQLdb for python2.7

Tags: python-2.7, mysql-python

I have various versions of python (python2.4 and python2.7) installed on the CentOS machine. I installed MySQL-python, but I can only import the MySQLdb module on python2.4 **but not python2.7**

```
root# python2.7
Python 2.7.11 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Dec  6 2015, 18:08:32) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
>>> import MySQLdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named MySQLdb

root# python
Python 2.4.3 (#1, Mar  5 2011, 21:26:05) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-50)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import MySQLdb
>>>
```

I've tried alias'ing python to /usr/bin/python2.7 and then doing a 'yum remove MySQL-python' and then doing a 'yum install MySQL-python' but no luck. Any clues/insights? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The yum will install the MySQL-python to the system default python's directory.

maybe you can try virtualenv and pip.

1. install the pip
2. ## pip install virtualenv
3. ## virtualenv -p /the/localtion/of/python27 python27
4. active the new python envirement, and pip install MySQL-python